# Show C# generated bitmap in VBA Form

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access, bitmap

I want to show a bitmap (a qr-code) which is generated at runtime in an C#-library (without have to save it as a file.

So I created a COM-visible class/library which I am able to call out of my VBA-Form (ms-access).

But now Im stuck. Which datatype I have to use to transfer the image(System.Drawing.Bitmap) from C# to VBA? And how am I able to display this image in a form?

Comment: At the moment I use System.Drawing.Bitmap (but this can be changed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your current code?

You can convert your Image/Bitmap to a byte array which can be consumed by VBA Image control.

```
public byte[] GetPicture()
{
    return YourMethodThatReturnsByteArrayFromImage(Image image);
}
```

and in vba `Image.pictureData = ComObject.GetPicture()`

Comment: Note that the bytes contain a device-dependent bitmap, thus are unsuited for storing. If the C# runs locally that's fine, if you want to store/send the data, you want to use a device-independent bitmap instead (the image control in Access can handle DIBs as picture data as well).

Comment: btw: I used this code:  byte[] BitmapToBytes(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                memory.Position = 0;

                return memory.ToArray();
            }
        } to transform my System.Drawing.Bitmap to a byte-array

Comment: @Erik A: I use the image just for display (and printing). So device-dependent is ok. But thank you for the Info anyway.